# Problem with Folders in Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

i'm new at Ubuntu One.

I've just uploaded a file and I want to get it into a folder. Seems like a stupid question but I've been trying and I couldn't. How do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: What is U1? Also, 'folder' is not a descriptive tag, neither is the title clear.

Answer (score 4):

I'm presuming you are talking about the web-interface here. I'm also presuming that you haven't set up Ubuntu One on the Desktop. Please let me know if this is not the answer you're looking for.

---

You can't, at the moment, move files into folders from the Web-Interface. Go to your desktop and move the file there instead.

- To set up Ubuntu One on your dektop, go to the **Me Menu** and select **Ubuntu One**:

  [image]
- A web browser will open and ask you to **sign in**.
- Select **Add this Computer**
- Back in the preferences dialogue, select the **Devices*** tab and click the **Connect** button.

You should now be able to move the files around in, for example, the *Ubuntu One* directory in your Home directory.

Do allow some time for synchronisation. You can check the status in the *Ubuntu One Preferences* dialogue.

---

You may also be interested in the [[image] Ubuntu One](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Tutorials/Setup) page in the Ubuntu Wiki. It explains how to set up Ubuntu One in detail.